# Running CONEMU from CMD with parameters

Tags: conemu

I have such a string

```
"Port knocking\knock\knock.exe" XXX.XXX.X.XXX 1111 & "Port knocking\knock\knock.exe" XXX.XXX.X.XXX 2222 & "Port knocking\knock\knock.exe" XXX.XXX.X.XXX 3333 & ssh root@XXX.XXX.X.XXX -p 6325 -i "SSH_Keys\private_key-openssh_new" & -new_console:n:P:"^<Solarized Git^>":d:"Port knocking\knock\":t:"ROOT"
```

I want to run this from the Total Commander button.
If I do it in CMD, everything works, as I need, but this line is too long, and it does not fit in the command field of button TC (as well as in the "Start Menu->Run").
How can I run Conemu with such parameters

Comment: Try Tasks. https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html

Comment: Tasks works for me and configured, but you inattentively read the question

"I want to run this from the Total Commander button."

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. Run your task from TC.

Comment: Ооо, так можно! БлагоДарю!
Ooo so you can! Thank you!